# combination of elements from vectors

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have several vectors `a=[1 2 3 ...]`, `b=[1 2 3 ...]`, `c=[1 2 3 ...]`. I have to find all possible combinations composed from elements taken from each of these vectors like:

```
[1 1 1]
[1 1 2]
[3 3 3]
etc.
```

The problem is that I have to exclude combinations containing same elements since order does not matter. For example, it the combination `[1 2 1]` is presented, the combination `[2 1 1]` should be excluded. How can I do that in any programing language (python is preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work if you're not that worried about efficiency.

```
from itertools import product

def specialCombinations(*vectors):
  return {tuple(sorted(i)): i for i in product(*vectors)}.values()
```

It takes the Cartesian product of the input vectors and filters the
ones equivalent under permutation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I have completely understood your requirements, but you may find that [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is helpful.

For example:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cr
for a in cr([1,2,3],3):
   print a
```

prints

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 3)
```